# Renaming each row in column to the column name

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have multiple dataframes in a list, with each dataframe representing a different time series location.

Each station dataframe element is currently within a list in a similar format to the following:

`data.frame(Station1_1 = c(1:365),DayOfYear = 1:365, Temperature = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)))`

`data.frame(Station2_1 = c(1:365),DayOfYear = 1:365, Temperature = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)))`

I plan to merge the dataframes together, but want to preserve the station number information (Station1 etc.) for each dataframe. Therefore I would like to rename each row in column 1 to the column name so that I don't have to enter the individual station names, and the script will take that information from the dataframe itself.

An example of the desired output would be:

`data.frame(Station1_1 = c("Station1"),DayOfYear = 1:365,Temperature = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)) )`

A bonus would be if the "_1" could also be removed from the end of each name?

I'm not sure if a looping function would be best or if there is some other base R function to do this?

Comment: Could you add what has failed? Also maybe add some variety in station names to make it easier to follow. At least I find it a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Station1_1 = c(1:365),DayOfYear = 1:365, Temperature = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)))
#Code
df$Station1_1 <- sub("_[^_]+$", "", names(df)[1])
```

Output (some rows):

```
head(df)
  Station1_1 DayOfYear Temperature
1   Station1         1   11.819052
2   Station1         2   11.272291
3   Station1         3    9.711139
4   Station1         4   13.338525
5   Station1         5    9.276242
6   Station1         6    8.631387
```

Comment: This appears to work great for a single dataframe, but i can't seem to implement it across multiple dataframes within a list. Would you have any thoughts?

Comment: @KevinPurves Yeah, it is easy, you can pack the code into a function and then use `lapply()` over your list so that you will get your dataframes transformed!

Comment: @KevinPurves Actually I am not at home, but maybe in 7 hours if you like you can invite me to chat and I can explain how to pack the code in a function for using on a list, if you wish!

Comment: That's okay, I would 100% take you up on that kind offer, but I'm doing a handover of the work to my manager, so i'll leave a comment with what you've suggested and they'll probably be able to figure it out. Thank you!